# extjs clearfilters() does nto execute immediately?

Tags: extjs

When one fires the Grid.filters.clearFilters() command, does it execute immediately?
My problem is:
I do :

```
Grid.filters.clearFilters();
```

Then later.elsewhere...

```
filters.buildQuery = function(filters){
for(var i=0, len=filters.length; i<len; i++) {..custom logic.}
}
```

It goes in a infinite loop. It appears the state of the filters obj here is not defined properly.
When I put an `alert()` just before for loop, the alert gives it enough time to clear filters and it works fine.

What can I do to ensure that the clearfilters is completed before filters.buildQuery starts to execute? Something of the java equivalent of

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
t1.jon();//so all other thread wait.
```

Comment: what is Grid? what is it's ext type? A grid panel? There is no native 'filters' property on a grid in the API, therefore you shouldn't be using it or it doesn't exist.

Comment: My guess: The 'filters' proeprty becomes available after you do :Grid.initPlugin(filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid.filters (I assume u mean ux.Gridfilters plugin) works fine with ext grid.

I'd say first remove an extra parameter in the loop, and see what happens then:)

**javascript loop syntax is :**

```
for (variable=startvalue;variable<=endvalue;variable=variable+increment)
{
     code to be executed
}
```